# Django Allauth migration error

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've run across this issue before and I think I had to go into the library installed by pip to manually delete the migrations to fix it.  Does anyone have a better idea?

./manage.py makemigrations

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 95, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 268, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 238, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 261, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 261, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/Users/josh/.pyenv/versions/one_raft_first_site/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 104, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration socialaccount.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('sites', '0001_initial')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `django.contrib.sites` is not present in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. This package is a direct dependency of the `allauth` package.

It is referenced in the [installation section of the documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> settings.py (Important - Please note ‘django.contrib.sites’ is required as INSTALLED_APPS)

and your error says that explicitly:

> Migration socialaccount.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('sites', '0001_initial')

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I do have django.contrib.sites in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: before than `allauth`? (on the list)

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the problem occurred because you have defined `settings.MIGRATION_MODULES` setting for the `sites` app. And the module doesn't have all the necessary migrations on which `allauth` relies.

There are two solutions.

- Copy migrations from `$PYTHON_HOME/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/migrations` to the folder which is specified in your settings.
- Remove `sites` from that setting.